# Firebase Data Collection with Unique Member

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unique-index

I would like to show a list of toys.
ach toy as a unique name.
The name can contain any character, so it can have a dot a slash or a dollar.
This is why I would prefer to use the push method to get a generated key.

The code I end up with is troublesome.
It is not thread safe and I could end up with duplicate toys. 
Is there a better way?

```
var child = testsRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Meccano");

return child.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var snap = snapshot.val();
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    alert('Toy ' + value + ' already exists.');
  } else {
    var newPostKey = testsRef.push().key;
    var updates = {};
    updates[newPostKey] = {          name: value        };
    var result = testsRef.update(updates);
    alert('We can only assume that it has worked.' + result);
  }
});
```

I built a complete working codepen to illustrate my question here:
http://codepen.io/paganaye/pen/EWrayY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the toy name as the key but first run it through a firebase key sanitizer like:

```
function fbKeySanitizer(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[.$[\]#\/]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

You can either save the original name as a property like you would with the push() method or you can use decodeURIComponent() to reverse the encoding to get back to the exact same string.

Comment: I hear what you say.
Your function does replace far too many characters though.
What about:

function fbKeySanitizer(str) {
  return str.replace(/[%.$[\]#\/]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
}

Comment: That would probably work but being URL safe is handy at least in my situation. Once you pick an encoding, stick with it. Lookups fail if you start encoding differently even if they losslessly round-trip.

Comment: I think your regexp is broken though, you need a escape on the first close square bracket. `"%.$[]#/".replace(/[%.$[]#\/]/g,'*')` => `"%.$[]#/"` but `"%.$[]#/".replace(/[%.$[\]#\/]/g,'*')` => `"*******"`

Comment: Thanks for that.
I did put the slash before the bracket though.
It looks like the comment editor stripped it out.
[For the record I ended up with this](http://codepen.io/paganaye/pen/PpVQZy)
`function fbKeySanitizer(str) {
  return str.replace(/[%.$[\]#\/]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution using Unicode characters.
For example the # character is replaced by a very similarequals sign and slanted parallel : '⧣'.

```js
var nameElt = document.getElementById("name");
var sanitizedElt = document.getElementById("sanitized");
var sanitized2Elt = document.getElementById("sanitized2");
var decodedElt = document.getElementById("decoded");
var outpuElt = document.getElementById("output");
var decoded2Elt = document.getElementById("decoded2");


function fbKeySanitizer(str) {
  return str.replace(/[%.$[\]#\/]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
}

var unicodeReplacements = {
  '.':'․', // One dot leader
  '$':'ᙚ', // Canadian syllabics carrier: sh
  '[':'⟦', // Mathematical left white square bracket
  ']':'⟧', // Mathematical right white square bracket
  '#':'⧣', // Equals sign and slanted parallel 
  '/':'⧸' // big solidus
}
var decodeUnicodeReplacements = {};
for (var prop in unicodeReplacements) {
  decodeUnicodeReplacements[unicodeReplacements[prop]]=prop;
}

function fbKeySanitizer2(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.$[\]#\/]/g, function (c) {
    return unicodeReplacements[c];
  });  
}

function fbDecoded2(str) {
  return str.replace(/[․ᙚ⟦⟧⧣⧸]/g, function (c) {
    return decodeUnicodeReplacements[c];
  });  
}

function nameKeyUp() {
  var sanitized1string = fbKeySanitizer(nameElt.value);
  sanitizedElt.innerText = sanitized1string;
  decodedElt.innerText =  decodeURIComponent(sanitized1string);

  var sanitized2string = fbKeySanitizer2(nameElt.value);
  sanitized2Elt.innerText = sanitized2string;
  decoded2Elt.innerText =  fbDecoded2(sanitized2string);
}
nameKeyUp();
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
<form>
  <h1>Firebase invalid key characters escaping</h1>
  <label for="name">name:</label>
  <input id="name" onkeyup="nameKeyUp()" value="A%.B[#0]/x" />
  <hr>
  <form>
  <h3>Method One</h3>
  <p>Sanitized1: <span id="sanitized"></span></p>
  <p>Decoded1: <span id="decoded"></span></p>
  <hr>
  <h3>Method Two</h3>
  <p>Sanitized2: <span id="sanitized2"></span></p>
  <p>Decoded2: <span id="decoded2"></span></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting idea: pros: it would be much easier to paste into URLs in the console cons: any char encoding mistakes would leave you with ascii soup, I can't type those chars from the keyboard, those chars are no longer available, you are left with a subset of unicode

Comment: Agreed.
I started with a subset of ascii and I end up with a subset of unicode.

Comment: Not really, for the purposes of round-tripping URI encoding can take any unicode in and get back to the exact same string. Try encoding and then decoding the following string with your functions: `".$[\]#\/]․ᙚ⟦⟧⧣⧸"` and see what you get back. URI encoding/decoding is lossless.

Comment: What I meant was.
Using firebase you can't use:   '.$[]#/'
Using my (somewhat dysfunctional function) you can't use:   '․ᙚ⟦⟧⧣⧸'
It might be sufficient for some of us.